# can't catch Promise queue errors

Tags: node.js, promise, queue, spawn

I'm setting up a node app where I have to run a series of asynchronous spawn tasks in order, so I've got a queue system set up.  It runs well when it reaches no errors.  However, it's failing to catch the errors and log them when they do happen.  Here's where I am right now:

```
function queue(tasks) {
    let index = 0;
    const runTask = (arg) => {
        if (index >= tasks.length) {
            return Promise.resolve(arg);
        }
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            tasks[index++](arg).then(arg => resolve(runTask(arg))).catch(reject);
        });
    }
    return runTask();
}

function customSpawn(command, args) {
    return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const child = spawn(command, args, {windowsVerbatimArguments: true});
        child.on('close', code => {
            if (code === 0) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The queue is built and executed like this:

```
myqueue.push(customSpawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', convertpath, filelist[i], '-interlace', 'line', '-chop', croppixels, '-resize', '300', outfile]));
queue(myqueue).then(([cmd, args]) => {
        console.log(cmd + ' finished - all finished');
    }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error(error.stack);
            });
```

The following error is thrown:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not a function(…)`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `.catch(TypeError, function(e) {})`? It's not valid JavaScript, `.catch` takes one argument.

Comment: Oh.  That's an oversight.  Let me try it with the one argument.

Comment: fixed it, but still getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I can't quite understand your `queue` function so I refactored it using `Array.prototype.reduce`.  This is a standard way to chain things in a compact way.  The following module models your case and will run in node.  It demonstrates how the error handling works.  I assume that you want to abort the whole chain if there is an error?

```
'use strict';
const insp = require('util').inspect;

const size = 10;
const throwAt = 6;

var template = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,];
var cmds = template.map((_, i) => ({cmd: `cmd ${_}`, args: [`arg1-${i}`, `arg2-${i}`]}));
var queue = [];

// promise factory
function makePromise (command, args) {
  return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(_ => {if(command.indexOf(throwAt) > 0) {
      return reject(command);  // whatever is passed here will hit the catch
    }
    console.log(`${command}\t${insp(args)}`);
    resolve()
    }, Math.random() * 1000)
  })
}

// populate the queue
cmds.forEach(c => queue.push(makePromise(c.cmd, c.args)));
// then execute it and catch all errors
queue.reduce((q, p) => q.then(p), Promise.resolve())
  .catch(e => console.log(`error: ${e}`));
```

You can also add some re-try logic like this...

```
// promise factory
function makePromise (command, args) {
  return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(_ => {
      if(command.indexOf(throwAt) > 0 && command.indexOf('retry') === -1) {
        return makePromise(command + 'retry', args)()
          .then(_ => resolve(), e => reject(e));
      }
      console.log(`${command}\t${insp(args)}`);
      resolve()
    }, Math.random() * 1000)
  })
}
```

### Error propagation

Playing around with this, I noticed that any error thrown inside a a `resolve` or a `reject` callback will result in the `reject` of the calling block being called, passing the error object as the single argument. This means that the error can be thrown rather than just calling `reject`.  This has the benefit of delivering a stack trace also.

### Managing the cascade

By adding a `reject` callback to each promise in the chain, the error propagation can be managed if needed.  If a `reject` calback is added however, it must re-throw the error if it needs to be propagated.

Here is a an implementation of these two principles...

```
function makePromise2 (command, args) {
  return (retry) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(retry){
      console.log(`throw at ${command}`);
      throw new Error(`sorry, tried twice!`);
    }
    setTimeout(_ => {
      if(command.indexOf(throwAt) > 0) {
/*
        if(retry)   // throwing here will not be handled
          throw new Error(`sorry, tried my best!`);
*/
        return makePromise2(command, args)(true)
          .then(resolve, reject);  // without this it will fail silently
      }
      console.log(`${command}\t${insp(args)}`);
      resolve();
    }, Math.random() * 1000)
  })
}

function Reject (cmd) {
  return function reject (e) {
  console.log(`re-throw at ${cmd.cmd}`);
  throw e;  // if you have a reject callback then you must propagate the error
}}

// populate the queue
cmds.forEach(c => queue.push(makePromise2(c.cmd, c.args)));
// then execute it and catch all errors
// the Reject gives the opportunity to manage the error cascade
queue.reduce((q, p, i) => q.then(p, Reject(cmds[i])), Promise.resolve())
  .catch(e => console.log(`catch...\n${e.stack}`));
```